# Using a OR'ed Enum in a custom UITypeEditor

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I have a property on a custom control I have written that is an Flag based Enum. I created my own custom control to edit it in a way that makes logical sense and called it from my own UITypeEditor. The problem is that Visual Studio generates an error when the value I attempt to store is a combination of the flags it tells me the value is invalid.

Example:

```
public enum TrayModes
{ 
    SingleUnit = 0x01
  , Tray = 0x02
  , Poll = 0x04
  , Trigger = 0x08
};
```

If the value I want to save is `SingleUnit | Trigger` the value generated is 9. Which in turn creates the following error:

[image: Code generation for the property 'TrayMode' failed. Error was: 'The value '9' is not valid for the enum 'TrayModes'.']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `[Flags]` before your enum declaration

```
[Flags]
public enum TrayModes
{ 
    SingleUnit = 0x01
   , Tray = 0x02
   , Poll = 0x04
   , Trigger = 0x08
};
```

Consider using HasFlag function to check for setted flags

```
TrayModes t=TrayModes.SingleUnit|TrayModes.Poll;
if(t.HasFlag(TrayModes.SingleUnit))
//return true
```

Edit:
That's because enum with flags attribute are threated in a different way,
as you can see in the example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx
A To string of enum with and without Flags attribute show how they are different

All possible combinations of values of an
Enum without FlagsAttribute:

```
  0 - Black
  1 - Red
  2 - Green
  3 - 3
  4 - Blue
  5 - 5
  6 - 6
  7 - 7
  8 - 8
```

All possible combinations of values of an
Enum with FlagsAttribute:

```
  0 - Black
  1 - Red
  2 - Green
  3 - Red, Green
  4 - Blue
  5 - Red, Blue
  6 - Green, Blue
  7 - Red, Green, Blue
  8 - 8
```

Comment: I already have noted this, buy why do I have to add it? The set in your example code works without the attribute, but the situation I have generates an error. Also I do not have the `HasFlag` method as I am on C# 2.0

Comment: Yes it changes the `ToString` results but if you look at that example you can even see that the any value is still a valid value for the enum without the Flags attribute. Otherwise you an error would be generated on the cast before the `ToString`. Any `int` should still be a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute on the enum will prevent the error from happening. This is a mystery to me as storing an ORed enum without the flag is valid and can be done in the code (With a proper cast).