# Shall I use [Flags] on all enum types in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Is it best practice to use the `[Flags]` ahead of all, even the simplest `enum` types like this in C# (VS 2015):

```cs
[Flags]
public enum TValidation
{
    vUninitialized, vChecksumPass, vChecksumFail, vChecksumZero, vChecksumNone
}
```

---

Am I clear such use I presented will always be ok with or without `[Flags]`? Or can it have some unintended side-effects?

Comment: Use Flags when you need it, and do not use it when you just need unique values to represent something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the \[Flags\] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c).  Once you read this you’ll know why your question doesn’t make sense

Comment: Whether you use it or not should depend whether you're going to use the enum as a bit flag. Just applying attributes indiscriminately is never a good idea.

Comment: @DavidG *hint: it does virtually nothing* ... [not true](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VDno7v)

Comment: @Selvin So what do you think it does that isn't virtually nothing?

Comment: @DavidG It changes the way `ToString()` works with the enum, for starters.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, that's the *something*.

Comment: @DavidG That's the *something* which means that it doesn't do `virtually nothing`, though...

Comment: @DavidG It also makes a difference if using the enum as a property for a Control, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663166/using-a-ored-enum-in-a-custom-uitypeeditor).